# Google prettify plugin on IE browser not working

Tags: javascript

I am using [Google Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) to generate a JavaScript document preview.

The plugin works in Chrome (if I refresh the page 2 to 3 times), but not in IE9 and IE11.

Due to dynamic rendering, I can't set `onload="prettyPrint();"` on my `body` tag, so I am using

```
<script>window.onload = prettyPrint </script>
```

I also tried this, with the same result

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        prettyPrint()
    });
</script>
```

I tried to debug **run_prettify.js** but it says `undefined`

```
var prettyPrint;
```

Here is the [documentation](https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)

calling js file in end of body.

```
<script src="${url.context}/res/components/preview/code-prettify-master/prettify.js?autoload=true&amp;lang=css'" />
<script src="${url.context}/res/components/preview/code-prettify-master/run_prettify.js" />
<script src="${url.context}/res/components/preview/code-prettify-master/lang-css.js" />
```

this is the code, where i am generating `<pre>` tags

```
var resultDiv = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName("previewer CodePrettifyMaster")[0];
var preDiv = document.createElement('pre');
preDiv.id = this.wp.id + '_prettify';
preDiv.className = "prettyprint lang-scm linenums";
var ganttContentDiv = document.createElement('div');
ganttContentDiv.id = 'contentContainer';
ganttContentDiv.appendChild(preDiv);
resultDiv.appendChild(ganttContentDiv);
```

Comment: First, Google Prettify has moved to [GitHub](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). Are you sure you're using the last version of it? Also, they provide a [test page](https://rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/tests/prettify_test.html) you can open with any browser to check if it's compatible.

Comment: @pistou it is  working in IE for test page, i am working in CMS <body> tag is already defined, so i am not able to inject prettyPrint() on onload();

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md) of the last version, you don't have to inject anything. All you have to do is to add `run_prettify.js` to you page and make sure you have proper code to prettify. Could you provide us the code you have to prettify?

Comment: @pistou update the code